# LocalBroadcastManager in ndk

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk

Is it possible to send or receive data with **LocalBroadcastManager** in a java interface? Send or to receive in ndk (**c** or **c++**)?

I know how to implement **LocalBroadcastManager** in java but I want to know if is it possible to use it in **c** in order to exchange data and where can I read about this feature.

So I would like to know what is the equivalent c function to **JAVA** LocalBroadcastManager.

Comment: All that Java functionality is perfectly available to NDK code - via unsightly reflection. There's no C equivalent except calling into Java.

Comment: It is a feature that should exist simplify a lot the complexity of the code.

Comment: "Should", huh? The platform doesn't owe you anything. Don't be lazy. The functionality is available, stop complaining and start coding. A true software engineer scoffs at complexity.

Comment: I'm already developing that solution... ;) I just post this to have certainty about the impossibility... Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt it. You can't use intent in `ndk`, this is a limitation of `ndk` - so you can't receive or send any broadcast. I suggest You to make an upcall to `java` when you need to send, and `java` will do the rest. Receiver also must be in `java`.